# Why it is possible to pass an other type

Tags: scala

I have following code snippet:

```
sealed trait Option[+A] {

  def map[B](f: A => B): Option[B] = this match {
    case None => None
    case Some(a) => Some(f(a))
  }

  def getOrElse[B>:A](default: => B): B = this match {
    case None => default
    case Some(a) => a
  }

  def orElse[B>:A](ob: => Option[B]): Option[B] =
    this.map(Some(_)).getOrElse(ob)

}

case class Some[+A](get: A) extends Option[A]
case object None extends Option[Nothing]
```

The function `orElse` has a argument `ob` of type `Option[B]`. In the function body, I pass `ob` to the function `getOrElse` but it expects a type of `B`, how it is possible?

Because `B` can be any type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type `A` is identified once at the top. Type `B`, on the other hand, is being identified/defined separately at each method.

So if `orElse` receives an `Option[B]` for some unknown type `B` and passes it to `getOrElse` then, as far as `getOrElse` is concerned, that becomes the new `B`.

This might make a little more sense if you had used `C` instead of `B` for the `getOrElse` method, and used `D` instead of `B` for the `orElse` method. Everything would work the same but it'd be easier to see the non-relationships.

It's analogous to value parameters. If we have a method `f(x:Int) = g(x-1)` the received parameter is called `x`. The method `g(x: Int)=...` also calls its parameter `x` but that doesn't mean the values are the same.